# Keep NSDictionary value updated with its underlying object value

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

EDIT: REAL SITUATION

MyAppDelegate has these resources:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *page1;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *page2;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *page3;
```

Here's what they look like when I init them:

```
self.page1 = @{@"videoPath":myPath, @"leftText":self.buttonTitle1, @"menuButtons":@[page2,page3]};
self.page2 = @{@"videoPath":myPath, @"leftText":@"long text", @"menuButtons":@[page1,page3]};
self.page3 = @{@"videoPath":myPath, @"leftText":@"another text", @"menuButtons":@[page1,page2]};
```

So each *menuButtons* key holds a reference to other objects.

Take this example: at a certain point user edits the *buttonTitle1* variable, writing a new text (eg: "my new button title").
I'd like other dictionarios (*page2* and *page3*) will reflect this modification, so inspecting *page2[@"menuButtons"]* will give me an NSArray of "my new button title" (page1's *leftText* key) and "another text" (page3's *leftText* key).

Consider that there are around 100 *page*s and users can edit *buttonTitle1* several times.

How can I keep my dictionaries updated?

---

ORIGINAL -NOT DETAILED- QUESTION:

Given a NSDictionary with a key and a value, I'd like to keep the contents of NSDictionary updated, so when someone will edit the value OUTSIDE the NSDictionary it will reflect that modification.
I don't know how to explain this in english, so please take this example:

```
NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"test":number};
NSLog(@"%@", dict); // print "test = 1"
number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:2];
NSLog(@"%@", dict); // print "test = 1" but I'd expect "test = 2"
```

I know that NSDictionary takes a copy of the object, so is there any other component or workaround to accomplish this?

Please note that I've tried with NSMutableDictionary and aslo with NSMapTable with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

`NSDictionary` doesn't take a copy of the object, it takes a copy of the key.

What you are doing is changing a pointer unassociated with the dictionary, so the dictionary has no idea it changed. You can't really make the dictionary aware.

What you can do is to put a mutable object into the dictionary and then change its internal state. A wrapper class will do if you need to.

For instance if you put a mutable dictionary into the dictionary and then change the contents of the mutable dictionary (not a pointer to the mutable dictionary though, take care here) and log the dictionary you will see the resulting log output change.

Comment: How can I change the mutable dictionary and not the pointer? Using `[NSDictionary setObject:forKey:] ` ?? When I need to update the mutable dictionary I don't know the "parent" dictionary in which the mutable is...

Comment: the point is that you mutate the object in the dictionary, where are your example changes something outside the dictionary

Comment: Yes of course I'd like to change something otuside the dictionary and have a pointer in the dictionary to that object, so it'll always be updated. Maybe I've to move away from NSDictionary and use something else...

Comment: you need to mutate the object, not change the pointer, so yes, like calling `setObject:forKey:` rather than setting something `=`. The dictionary isn't the problem, what you are changing is.

Comment: ok I understood. But consider if the number in my example will be inside 100 dictionaries I'd have to update all the dictionaries with `setObject:forKey:` ... ??! I hope there must be another approach.

Comment: if 100 dictionaries all contain a reference to the same mutable object then you only have 1 object to change...

Comment: Why use so many dictionaries then? and not core data or even a plist file? and even in for the mutable dictionaries declared in your AppDelegate, you just have to update the values of those mutable dictionaries by getting a reference of it from the appDelegate. As simple as        [ appDelegate. page1 setValue: yourValue forKey: yourKey ];

Comment: @Apple_iOS0304 this is simply an example to demonstrate the problem faced by the OP. Without true details you can't suggest an appropriate solution. And storing data in the app delegate is basically never the correct solution, merely a convenient one.